# Are commands such as these batch files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am reading Michael Hartl's Ruby On Rails Tutorial, and as customary with many programming tutorials he's having me use command line commands such as

```
bundle install
rake db:migrate
```

I'm just wondering what type of commands these are. I've read a little bit on batch files, and from what I've read it seems like these would be the batch files I've read of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you are actually executing batch files as windows does not have shebang support. For example the batch file for bundle is this:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "C:/Ruby193/bin/bundle" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

If you check in wherever you've got Ruby installed and go into the bin directory you'll see all the Ruby commands along with corresponding batch files to enable them to be executed without having to call ruby manually.

Answer (score 2):

`db:migrate` is a rake task.

`bundle install` is the same as Rake, a Ruby program, taking a command line arguments.

Not sure about the SASS version of bootstrap, but it's unlikely to be just a batch file in the end.

You can find out what they are by looking at them (well, db:migrate is a task so you'll have to do a bit more legwork to get to the implementation, you're actually *running* `rake`, which under Unix is a shebanged Ruby script; appended. I don't know what they are under Windows.)

---

Rake is a Ruby program, executed by the program after the shebang (`"#!"`), i.e., the Ruby interpreter.

```
#!/Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first =~ /^_(.*)_$/ and Gem::Version.correct? $1 then
  version = $1
  ARGV.shift
end

gem 'rake', version
load Gem.bin_path('rake', 'rake', version)
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. Will I be able to tell a batch file by whatever I write ending in .bat?

Comment: @AlexMelville If you're on a Windows machine, yes. If you're on OS X/Unix the commands might end with `.sh`, or nothing.